# I get more than one id in one click (ListView custom adapter GetView)

Tags: android, listview, getview

I want to do that when I click a ToggleButton from the list, retrieve the ID of the row textview. The problem is that when most IDS pulse are obtained, and when I scroll too ... I do not know what to do!

[image]

I get all these IDS in my LogCat.. with only ONE CLICK on the position "adeww"

[image]

My MyAdapter code is here:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Usuari>{

        private final List<Usuari> list;
        private final Activity context;


        public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Usuari> list) {
            super(context, R.layout.row, list);
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            protected TextView nom_usuari;
            protected ToggleButton boto_agregar;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.nom_usuari = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nom_usuari);
                viewHolder.boto_agregar = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.boto_agregar);


                viewHolder.boto_agregar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the togglebutton using setTag.
                        list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of togglebutton to maintain its state.
                        String nom = list.get(getPosition).getName();
                        if(isChecked)
                        {
                            Log.d("SELECCIONAT",nom);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.d("DESSELECCIONAT",nom);

                        }
                    }
                });


                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.nom_usuari, viewHolder.nom_usuari);
                convertView.setTag(R.id.boto_agregar, viewHolder.boto_agregar);
                } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            viewHolder.boto_agregar.setTag(position); // This line is important.            
            viewHolder.nom_usuari.setText(list.get(position).getName());
            viewHolder.boto_agregar.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());




            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: hmm I think you need to move line `viewHolder.boto_agregar.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());` before you set `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to it.

Comment: Yes, now I only get one Id, but now when I scroll, more than one togglebuttons are selected...

Comment: Why not use `position` parameter instead of `getPosition`. Like `final int viewPosition = position` and then use `viewPosition` in your `OnCheckedChangeListener`. Not sure does this fix it but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATENTION! I found the solution!! I had to delete the IF and ELSE condition...

I hope that it helps you! I spent two weeks to fix it!

```
  public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Usuari> {

    private final List<Usuari> list;
    private final Activity context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Usuari> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView nom_usuari;
        protected ToggleButton boto_agregar;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.nom_usuari = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.nom_usuari);
        viewHolder.boto_agregar = (ToggleButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.boto_agregar);

        viewHolder.boto_agregar.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        final int viewPosition = position;

        viewHolder.boto_agregar
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {

                        list.get(viewPosition).setSelected(
                                buttonView.isChecked());
                        String nom = list.get(viewPosition).getName();
                        if (isChecked) {
                            Log.d("SELECCIONAT", nom);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("DESSELECCIONAT", nom);

                        }
                    }
                });

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.nom_usuari, viewHolder.nom_usuari);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.boto_agregar, viewHolder.boto_agregar);

        viewHolder.boto_agregar.setTag(position); // This line is important.
        viewHolder.nom_usuari.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

And the Usuari class:

```
public class Usuari {

        private String nom;
        private boolean selected;

        public Usuari(String nom, boolean selected) {
            this.nom = nom;
            this.selected =selected;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return nom;
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }
    }
```