# Image and buttons in ListView in android

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I have a listView that can get data from MySql using AsyncTask, but my problem is when i add some buttons and images in the ListView. I added some buttons but i can use it and the image won't display.

here's my code...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new Loadstudent().execute();

    ListView lv = getListView();



    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Maindetail.class);
            String sidlist = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tid)).getText().toString();
            String namelist = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sname)).getText().toString();
            i.putExtra(TAG_ID, sidlist);
            i.putExtra(TAG_NAME, namelist);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

class Loadstudent extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading students. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_student, "GET", params);

        Log.d("ALL student: ", json.toString());

        try {

            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if(success == 1) {
                student = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STUDENT);

                for (int i=0; i<student.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = student.getJSONObject(i);

                    sid = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    photo = c.getString(TAG_PHOTO);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID, sid);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_PHOTO, photo);

                    studentList.add(map);
                }
            }else {

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, studentList,
                        R.layout.list_main, new String[] {
                                TAG_PHOTO,TAG_ID, TAG_NAME},
                        new int [] { R.id.imageviewlist, R.id.tid, R.id.sname });
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

I student the lazyadapter from the net, but got a problem combining it to code.
there's any tutorial or link that can solved my problem would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to add buttons and images in every row of your listview?

Comment: @Jaume yes, well I add buttons and image but the button won't work on setOnClick... and the image i don't know how to display it, any help would be great. thanks for the comment

Comment: is image shown from local or url ?

Comment: yes, the url is correct, because when i check it, it display to my browser.

Answer (score 0):

hey try below approach-

```
       lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Maindetail.class);
            HashMap<String, String> data = studentList.get(position);
            String sidlist = data.get(TAG_ID);
            String namelist = data.get(TAG_NAME);
            i.putExtra(TAG_ID, sidlist);
            i.putExtra(TAG_NAME, namelist);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own adapter for the listview if you want to add extra components in every row layout.

It's not easy, but it's all here coded by me few time ago --> [ListView Custom Adapter getView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908588/i-get-more-than-one-id-in-one-click-listview-custom-adapter-getview)

I hope this helps you!

Comment: yeah right, it's not easy, but thanks, I think it's your post. do you have other class file in that android project?

Comment: @hPys you're welcome! if you think it's a possible solution mark the tick :P

Comment: is your data in the listview are from the database?

Comment: did you use asynctask to you main.java? for getting data in the database to listview

Comment: @hPys Yes, the data is from my external database. And yes, I used an asyntask to recieve the data using Httppost.